# TestNG: How to set additional data to be accessed in IReporter

Tags: testng

I have data generated at run time that i want to access in my CustomReporter class that implements IReporter.  How would one go about doing that?

Currently, when my test fails, I am adding the data to the ITestResult.setParameters() object/method, but someone said not to do that because it's not documented whether or not the Parameters() object is intended to be modified.  Instead, I should create and populate an object that can be accessible from IReporter(), but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i stored all the data i need in ITestContext.setAttribute() and retrieved it via .getAttribute().